# Save state of adapter in different instances of ListFragment

Tags: android, adapter, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment instantiated multiple times, I would like to save and restore the state of the adapter to perform the "onListItemClick" method correctly.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    mCallback.onPlaceClick(adapter.getItem(position));
}
```

When I open the app for the first time everything goes right, but when I click on an item and another Activity is created, when I go back to that fragment the items are in their position, but I get IndexOutOBoundsException in adapter.getItem(), it says that size is 0 but I can see the elements in the List!

How it's possible to save and restore the state of the adapter object? (it's an instance field of the ListFragment class)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Fragment.onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). if implement this and populate the `Bundle`, that same bundle will be passed back to you when your fragment is re-created.

how you save the state of your adapter in a bundle is another question. that's up to you, but one way for example would be to make the element class backing your adapter parcelable, and use [putParcelableArrayList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29). in your `onCreate()`, method, you'd do something like,

```
if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("myState")) {
  List<MyObj> objs = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("myState");
  myAdapter = new MyAdapter(..., objs, ...);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I solved just using only instance fields, avoiding any static field, in my code the problem was just that..!